# Migrate huge database from sqlite to Redis with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, redis, export, migrate

I have an SQLite database (16G). There are three columns (origin, destination, distance) in the table. I would like to export the database to Redis for a faster query by origin and destination. Currently, I use the following code to export to Redis.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)    
cur = conn.cursor()
r = redis.Redis()

# I loop the following code
cur.execute("SELECT o,d,DIST FROM network LIMIT [startloc] OFFSET [offset];")
distlist = cur.fetchall()
records = {'{},{}'.format(o, d): DIST for o, d, DIST in distlist}
with r.pipeline() as pipe:
    pipe.mset(records)
    pipe.execute()
r.save()
```

However, I cannot use multiprocess to speed up the exporting even if I don't need synchronous write because I use the SAVE command. Can I use BGSAVE to solve the issue? Or is there any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you call ```conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)    r = redis.Redis()``` on each loop? 
Why do you even call save on each loop?

Comment: @GuyKorland Thanks for asking! I modify the part about looping in the question. If I call save after all the mset and execute commands, I got an error saying "Background save already in progress".

Comment: You should call it once at the end

Comment: @GuyKorland Should I call execute once at the end too? Because I got the error when I call save once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix up 2 concepts in Redis here:

- Pipeline: Send multiple commands at once to Redis and get the response to all of them at once back to save network traffic.
- Persistence: Save the content of Redis to disk as Redis is an in-memory database per default, i.e. without using SAVE or BGSAVE.

A pipeline in Redis makes only sense if you group more than 1 command together which is not the case in your posted sample. Try calling MSET multiple times (e.g. 10k) and call execute once done.

Writing to disk definitely makes sense, but not more than once in a while, e.g. every 1h or like in your case at the very end of your import.

Regards, Martin